# Has anyone seen VS Code drop file extensions when selecting a filename from the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

I'm trying to experiment with ES6 modules using VS Code but falling at the first hurdle, I wonder if someone can explain how to do it correctly / what I am doing wrong?

I have three files all in the same directory:

`index.html, module.js and main.js`

The content of `module.js` is:

```
export let hello = "Hello from the firstModule!";
```

I have no errors or warnings in VS Code or the browser dev console about this file.

The content of `main.js` is:

```
import { hello } from "./module";
console.log(hello);
```

In the browser console I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

I don't know why I am getting this because the import is at the top level of the module, isn't it?

The content of the `index.html` file is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hey!</h1>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I tried changing the script tag to:

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

but then I get an error in the browser console of:

> Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/modules/module” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

So, the only success I have had is by writing the entire contents of `main.js` in the `html <script>` tag:

```
<script type="module">
      import { hello } from "./module.js";
      console.log(hello);
    </script>
```

which also has a `type` of `module` attribute, so I am completely at a loss as to where to go from here as the above outputs the following to the console correctly:

```
Hello from the firstModule!
```

My conclusion from this is that the `export` statement is working correctly in the `module.js` file but the `import` statement appears to be the problem in the `main.js` file.

OK! I thought I'd edit this question because I found the cause of the problem. Yes, it was indeed the missing `.js` extension, however, this was actually omitted by VS Code itself; as I discovered when importing a second module.

The phenomenon happened when typing:

```js
import { hey } from "./"
```

Now! At this point VS Code kindly gives you a file selection option. You select the correct file, which has the correct extension, and the job is good to go, except, the file extension is actually missing from the filename you just selected, so you end up with:

```js
import { hey } from "./module2"
```

rather than:

```js
import { hey } from "./module2.js"
```

Wow! What more can I say?

Comment: I have only built ES-Modules on the backend, but I know that the error you are getting is telling you that you are trying to load an HTML file to the module, which I know ESM doesn't allow. I also know that  **`import { hello } from "./module";`** should have the extension of the file your importing tacked onto the end of the filename like this:  **`import { hello } from "./module.js";`**

Comment: @JayDev such a silly mistake missing the .js extension. It works fine now, thank you. Please add it as an answer! Many thanks :)